coreutils man pages are missing in WSL Fedora
I installed Fedora 39 on WSL,
but I ran into some issues when I tried using man.
When I used the man command, I was getting no manual entry for ...
I had to remove tsflags=nodocs from /etc/dnf/dnf.conf.
I reinstalled man man-db man-pages and changed the MANPATH
and some commands started working,
but not basic commands like man ls and man bash.
Apparently they are part of the "coreutils" package,
so I tried reinstalling it, but commands from this package are not found. 
I tried looking for the man pages in /usr/share/man,
but I couldn't find any – but other pages are present;
for example, I installed fzf and its fzf.1.gz is present.

In Fedora, the man pages for coreutils are in package coreutils-common. You should reinstall that too.

i'm in awe, i have no idea how ive missed this even tho i've been to coreutils package page countless times, thanks good sir
